# How to find the concrete type of interface instance when using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm currently trying to create an instance of an object that was defined as an interface. Specifically:

```
public static class A {
    public static IList<string> SampleList { get; set; }

    public void Initialize() { 
        SampleList = new List<string>();
    }
}

// In some other class where I don't have an instance of A.
// This class is in a separate DLL + running in a separate process as A
var propertyInfo = typeof(A).GetProperty("SampleList");
propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetConstructors().Any(); // false
// ^ I would like this to be true
```

When SampleList is instead typed as a List instead of the interface (IList) I'm able to produce a constructor and instantiate an instance of this list. I have the same luck with Arrays + other instances that aren't defined as an interface.

Something else I noticed is that when I use List, and invoke PropertyType.GetInterfaces() I get a list of 8 interfaces while when I invoke the same command using an IList instance I only get 3 interfaces. In general I'm getting a lot less information.

I was wondering if it was possible to find out the concrete class itself? If so, how?

Comment: The property is of type IList. They is no more information on the type object. If you had an instance of that object then you could check the type

Comment: List is a concrete implementation of many interfaces, infact you state in your question it's 8, one of them is IList. IList implements some interfaces too,3 as you stated. That's why the number differs. And the resin you don't get the constructor with the IList typed property is that interfaces don't have constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Wu's answer should work if you already have an instance of an object on which you can call GetType.  If you just have a type like `IList<string>`, or any interface type, you won't find a constructor.  I think the closest you could get would be to search the assemblies in the AppDomain for a type that implements the interface and has a default constructor.

```
var interfaceType = typeof(IList<string>);
var ctor = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a =>
    {
        try
        {
            return a.GetTypes();
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Type[0];
        }
    })
    .Select(t => interfaceType.IsGenericType && t.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericArguments().Length == t.GetGenericArguments().Length && t.GetGenericArguments().All(a => a.GetGenericParameterConstraints().Length == 0) ? t.MakeGenericType(interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()) : t)
    .Where(interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom)
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetConstructors())
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 0);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to find any information about the instance itself if you have the name of the field + name of the classes?

Comment: This answer won't work so well. You won't find `List<string>` in the list returned by `GetTypes()`. You will only find `List<>`, which is not assignable to `IList<string>`. You will have to call `MakeGenericType` and see if the resulting type is assignable to an `IList`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetType()` to get the type of the concrete instance.

```
    var propertyInfo = typeof(A).GetProperty("SampleList");
    var propertysTypeHasConstructor = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetConstructors().Any(); // false
    Console.WriteLine(propertysTypeHasConstructor);

    var concreteInstanceType = A.SampleList.GetType();
    var concreteInstanceHasConstructor = concreteInstanceType.GetConstructors().Any(); // true
    Console.WriteLine(concreteInstanceHasConstructor);
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Updated the question to mention that an instance of A isn't available from where I'm reflecting.

Comment: You don't need an instance of `A`. You simply need the static property `A.SampleList` to be populated. If it's not populated, then the "type" is `null`.

Comment: I guess my point is that I am unable to do "A.SampleList" to obtain SampleList.There may be other situations where the property isn't static that I'd like to instantiate + manipulate.

Comment: If there's no instance, there is no concrete type. You can assign all kinds of objects to an `IList<string>`, including a `List<string>`, a `Collection<string>`, or even a `string[]`.  There is not enough information to automatically populate a property that is typed this way. Perhaps you should declare the property as a `List<string>` instead of an `IList<string>`. The other option is keep a table of interfaces and the concrete classes you want to go with them, e.g. in an [Unity container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) which can set properties for you automatically.